# the King's desire: life or the living?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, aseres-yemei-teshuva

To the *amida* prayer from *Rosh Hashana* through *Yom Kipur*, we add a brief prayer that starts:

> זָכְרֵנוּ לְחַיִּים מֶלֶךְ חָפֵץ בַּחַיִּים

ArtScroll translates that as:

> Remember us for life, O King Who desires life

But there's another way one might translate it:

> Remember us for life, O King Who desires the living

We see the *kal* verb חפץ in *Tanach* many times, sometimes with a direct object and other times with a ב־ object. Most often (always?), when the object is a person, there's a ב־. And we do see חיים=life as a direct (no ב־) object in Psalms 34:13. On the other hand, we also see מות=death as a ב־ object in Ezekiel 18:23,32; 33:11. And, indeed, most objects of חפץ generally use ב־. Plus, maybe the usage (transitivity) of חפץ changed between *Tanach* and when this prayer was written.

So my question is whether ArtScroll is right. Specifically: Is there any good source/argument for one or the other (or some other) possible translation of בַּחַיִּים in this prayer?

Comment: Is the question really about whether ArtScroll is correct or whether you are correct? Because I think it's more the latter.

Comment: @ezra, I _can't_ be right, since I didn't claim any particular translation is correct.

Comment: You've focused on an interesting nuance. However, in terms of G-d's "desires" as it relates to this expression, what would be the meaning of "life" if it didn't focus on humans who are alive? It seems like the same thing regardless of how we were to translate it.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that Art Scroll's translation is correct. I think the definition is meant to be consistent and, in a sense, "poetic". All the other uses of the word חַיִּים, used here mean "life" not "living". E.g. זָכְרֵנוּ לְחַיִּים  means "Remember us for life", not "for the living". Same with all the other usages. I can't see a reason as to why there would be an interruption of definitions, here.

Comment: @DanF, I'm not sure "בספר החיים" is life, not the living… but that's for another question..

Comment: Yikes! I don't think we'd get a definitive answer to your last question unless you were able to see what that book really was. However, besides the consistent meaning suggestion that I mentioned, I think you could argue, that perhaps that book has instructions or a "prototype" for HOW each person would live during that year.

Comment: This is also an issue in tehillim 27.  When I say it in English, I alternate saying "Had I not trusted that I would see the goodness of HASHEM in the land of life!" and " [...] in the land of the living." Never knew which one was right, but I find meaning in them both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ר"י בן יקר in his commentary to that line writes:

> בבני אדם שהם חיים
>
> People who are alive

seemingly siding decisively with your non-Artscroll option.